# Checking file header for magic number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, error-handling, compression

I wrote this to check files for successful compression with [LZ4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)).

Any advice is welcome.

Particularly regarding raising exceptions and error handling.

```
import sys

def check_lz4_header(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        header = file.read(4)  # Read the first 4 bytes (typical size of LZ4 header)
        if header != b'\x04\x22\x4d\x18':  # Check for LZ4 magic number (optional)
            raise ValueError("Invalid header: This does not appear to be an LZ4 compressed file.")
        else:
            print("This appears to be an LZ4 compressed file.")

# If the script is run as a standalone script, execute the check_lz4_header function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python lz4_header_checker.py <file_path>", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        check_lz4_header(file_path)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```